# Bypass a function error

Tags: library

I have a long code written in Arduino101 that works fine. I use a prepared function (connected to a library) in my code that I have not written it. My input to this function is an array. In 99.9999..% of the time, the function works great. However, it might stops due to an unknown reason, maybe because of my wrong input. This causes the program to stop. 
My question is: how to bypass this function if it fails for any reason? Something like 'on error' function in normal programming.

Thanks a lot in advance,

Comment: *If* it is because of your input being bad, then you need to check and validate that input.

Comment: Please add more info to your question, mention that this is a follow-up of: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/61867/problem-with-variables

Comment: Thanks, friends. I will focus on my code to find the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

If your function is crashing then there is no way to recover. Arduinos are unprotected real mode devices. If your code does something invalid, your program crashes and the device will likely either hang or restart.

You need to debug your function, or find the invalid data you are passing into it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Duncan. I will do so.